# Optimal way to isolate an error

Tags: probability

I do not know the technical name of this problem but it goes something like this:

I have N modules and n of them are faulty. I can test for faults m modules at a time (testing m modules at once takes the same time as testing 1 module at a time)

What is the best strategy?

What if n is not known but it is defined by a probability function?

Comment: If there is a best strategy, presumably it involves carefully selecting which modules to select for each test. What does it mean for the number of modules, $m$, to be random?

Comment: @DavidK Sorry, I meant n, the number of faulty modules. In the case that we do not know exactly how many modules will be faulty.

Comment: I suppose a single test of $m$ modules returns "OK" if all modules pass, "fail" in any other case? It does not tell you which modules failed, or even how many failed?

Comment: @DavidK I would know if at least one module has failed

Comment: A naive approach would be to partition the modules into $\lceil N/m \rceil$ subsets of at most $m$ modules each, and run one test on each subset. If any test fails, then $n > 1$. Are there further complications that make this not a viable test strategy?

Comment: @DavidK I want to choose m